# Is Ubuntu Convergence possible on Nexus 5?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I wanted to experiment Ubuntu Convergence on my Nexus 5. I wanted to know if it is supported by Nexus 5 or is it only Nexus 4. Multirom has been installed and there are different versions of Ubuntu Touch, so which among these versions will help me converting my Ubuntu Touch to Desktop when connected via HDMI cable to a monitor.

Comment: I don't have the hardware available for testing, but based on [the differences in specifications](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/compare/Google-Nexus-5,Google-Nexus-4/phones/8148,7531) I don't see anything that would deter me from trying the version that was reported to work on the Nexus 4. For that matter it appears that almost everything is working on the [Nexus 5](https://devices.ubports.com/#/hammerhead)

Comment: Except that I am not able to install Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 5 via Multirom as a secondary ROM. It gets stuck on the Google logo during boot. And this happens on almost all of the channels.

Comment: Interesting. On what channel does it not occur?

Answer (score 0):

The UBports project lists Nexus 5 as an active device (can be used as a daily driver), codenamed [hammerhead](https://devices.ubports.com/#/hammerhead).

Comment: I just flashed it on my Nexus 5 but have been unable to get a connection to Wireless Displays. Samsung TV, MS Wireless Display and NowTV are all detected but it can't connect. MHL cable (USB mini to HDMI) also doesn't work.